# Combining several Hidden markov models

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I have 3 hidden markov models in python that I trained for each robot behaviours. Imagine I have 3 behaviours A, B and C. And for each of them I have a HMM model. Now I want to combine them together to have one HMM that can recognise a complex behaviour. A complex behaviour means combine A, B and C together. For example I give a sequence to the model and the results should be something like this. First B after that A after that C after ....
Now I have a question. How should I combine 3 or several HMM together? Generally, is it possible or not?
Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: What are your hidden states for the separate HMMs?

Comment: Are the behaviors A, B, and C independent?

Comment: Sounds like a Bayesian Network might be something you're looking for: https://pomegranate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BayesianNetwork.html#

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple HMM models together with independent states can be done with a
Factorial Hidden Markov Model. The original paper is by [Zoubin Ghahramani & Michael I. Jordan (1995)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1007425814087)

Several implementations exists in Python, for example [disaggregator.fhmm](https://github.com/dssg/wikienergy/blob/master/disaggregator/fhmm.py). It builds upon hmmlearn.